# CodeIgniter - Checking to see if a value already exists in the database

Tags: codeigniter

Im running CodeIgniter for a project of mine ... Im fairly new to this, i have the standard form validation checks for my form, except im unsure of how to check if the value already exists in the database.

This is what i have for my form validation rules so far

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('rolename', 'Role Name', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('rolekey', 'Role Key', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
```

The 'rolekey' is what i need to check against the 'rolekey' column in the database to see if it exists, if it does i need to shoot back an error.

Any help would be grand.

Cheers,

Answer (score 57, accepted):

There is not a built-in form validation check for whether or not a value is in the database, but you can create your own validation checks.

In your controller, create a method similar to this:

```
function rolekey_exists($key)
{
    $this->roles_model->role_exists($key);
}
```

And in your model that handles roles, add something like this:

```
function role_exists($key)
{
    $this->db->where('rolekey',$key);
    $query = $this->db->get('roles');
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

And then you can write a form validation check like this:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'callback_rolekey_exists');
```

See this page for more information:

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#callbacks-your-own-validation-methods

Comment: Thanks for the comment ... thats perfect ... Could you give me an example of the code i should use for the function? ... im still trying to get the hang of writing everything in functions. thanks

Comment: Thats perfect ... Thank you so much ... Just one more question, From that how does it return the error message 'rolekey already exists in the database'

Comment: within your role_exists function, add this: `$this->validation->set_message('role_exists', 'The %s already exists');` - put it just before the return true. also i think your returns might be confused - (might not matter but looking at CI docs). return FALSE if the validation fails, return TRUE if validation succeeds. I believe the code above will return true if there is a duplicate role. (meaning it will fail when a value DOESN'T exist. more @ http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/validation.html

Comment: Thanks for that ... Im getting an error in regards to the set_message in my model Call to a member function set_message() on a non-object

Comment: This is very good but I think ideally you'd move the if statement to the controller and not have any logic in the model.

Answer (score 14):

If you want to make your validation function available in more than one controller, you should include the rule in a MY_Form_validation library.

I do this in MY_Form_validation:

```
function exist($str, $value){       

  list($table, $column) = explode('.', $value, 2);    
  $query = $this->CI->db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM $table WHERE $column = $str'");
  $row = $query->row();

  return ($row->count > 0) ? FALSE : TRUE;

}
```

Then in your model (or controller) when you set your rules:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('username','username','exist[users.user_name]');
```

The rule calls the exist function.

The exist function explodes the string users.user_name at the dot and then queries the database to see if a record is returned. If it does, return false, else true. The rule will fail on a false return.

Comment: In you query you have missed a '

Answer (score 11):

You just edit your validation rule

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('rolename', 'Role Name', 'trim|required|xss_clean|is_unique[table_name.rolename]');
```

Comment: I agree, this would be the easiest method now. At the time this question was originally asked, however, the is_unique validation rule did not yet exist (it was added in CodeIgniter version 2.1, released November 14, 2011).

Comment: it worked for me, I am using codeigniter 4

Answer (score 6):

you can always just add

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('username','Username','is_unique[users.username]');
```

where user.username is the table.column

Answer (score 1):

Add the is_unique rule to your form validation as below

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('rolename', 'Role Name', 'trim|required|xss_clean|is_unique[your_database_table_name.rolename]');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('rolekey', 'Role Key', 'trim|required|xss_clean|is_unique[your_database_table_name.rolekey]');
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me might work for someone

In your controller, create a method similar to this:

```
function rolekey_exists('table','field','value')
{
  $this->roles_model->role_exists($key);
}
```

And in your model that handles roles, add something like this:

```
function role_exists($table,$field,$value)
{
    $this->db->where($field,$value);
    $query = $this->db->get($table);
    if (!empty($query->result_array())){
        return 1;
    }
    else{
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the new Codeigniter4 you can actually achieve that without need to add any method in your controller: with the is_not_unique rule you can check if a value is found in the database and return an error if it doesn't...basically doing the opposite of is_unique!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you want to check whether a value already exist in the database, it's correct to add is_unique in the validation side. So, you don't need to create a function in your controller to do it.

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('rolename', 'Role Name', 'trim|required|xss_clean|is_unique[table_name.table_field]');

$this->form_validation->set_rules('rolekey', 'Role Key', 'trim|required|xss_clean|is_unique[table_name.table_field]');
```

Then, you will see an error message in the input area. For example: **The username field must contain a unique value.**

I have tested it in Codeigniter 3.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

Little update for Codeigniter4

In CI4 you can use the validation rule "is_not_unique[table.field]" so do it in this way

```
$validation->setRule('email', 'Email', 'trim|required|valid_email|is_not_unique[users.email]');
```