# MySQL db entry won't load?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

This is coming from a log in form with email and password as the to fields:

```
echo form_open('main/login_validation');

echo "<P>Email: </br>";
echo form_input('email',$this->input->post('email'));
echo "</P>";

echo "<P>Password: </br>";
echo form_password('password');
echo "</P>";

echo "<P>";

$img_path = base_url()."imgs/log_in_0.png";

echo '<input type="image" src="'.$img_path.'">';
echo "</P>";

echo form_close();
```

Goes to the controler for form validation:

```
$this->load->library('form_validation');

$this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|trim|xss_clean|callback_validate_credentials');

$this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|trim');

if($this->form_validation->run()){
        $data = array(
            'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
            'is_logged_in' => 1
        );
        $this->session->set_userdata($data);

        $nKey ='members';
        $this->page($nKey);
    } else {
        $nKey ='login';
        $this->page($nKey);
    }
```

Callback sends it to:

```
public function validate_credentials(){
    $this->load->model('model_users');

    $salt = $this->model_users->get_salt();

    if($this->model_users->can_log_in($salt)){

        return true;
    }else{

    $this->form_validation->set_message('validate_credentials', 'Incorrect Email/Password.');
    return false;
    }

}
```

when it calls get_salt() it then loads from the model:

```
public function get_salt(){

    $this->db->where('email', $this->input->post('email'));


    $query = $this->db->get('users');

    if($query){

        $row = $query->row();

        $salt =  $row->salt;

        return $salt;
    }else{
        echo 'failed salt';

    }

}
```

this same code word fine two days ago, now it gives a non-object error on:

```
$salt =  $row->salt;
```

Won't load the query right, I echoed from the post array with codeigniter `function $this->input->post('email')`, and it echoed the correct email.

But when I `print_r` the query it comes back an empty query object, but the email is in the user db table (in the email field and everything), I have checked, I was using this same account to do tests just a few days ago

Comment: Does the field 'salt' realy exist in table 'users' ? With no upper case ?

Comment: yes and i found the problem, i had one letter wrong in the email, so there wasnt an entry, i looked and looked at that email and never notice the one letter difference

Comment: l spent an hour trying to find it, read that email at least 50 times and never registered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so i was getting the error because i entered the wrong pass word and it did test to see if the user existed.

code to test if user exist:

[CodeIgniter - Checking to see if a value already exists in the database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4296930/codeigniter-checking-to-see-if-a-value-already-exists-in-the-database)

in the accepted answer

Comment: one suggestion - you might want to check if the email exists in your  system separately. that way if someone is registered, but they accidentally put in the wrong password - you can tell them, hey we recognize you, but the password is incorrect.

Comment: if i do that i give an in to my data tables for a hacker, half the puzzle lets u know u solved it, instead i am going to implement a email system that will notify a person if their account has been attempted to be accessed 3 or more times with out the correct password, asking if it was them, and if they want to change their password, as well as have a password reset option on the site. then, if they say that it was not them, a copy of the (person that tried to access the account)'s ip and any other identifying info can be logged and the ip can even be banned from the site