# codeigniter form validation & ajax lookup to see if name exists

Tags: mysql, ajax, forms, codeigniter, validation

I have a form that allows me to add a new customer to a database table.

The customer_name field is a unique field. as such I want to perform form validation on the input field before an attempt is made to write to the database.

ideally, validation can be two fold. an ajax lookup to display if the name is available when the user enters a customer name. secondly, the validation functionality of codeigniter? should this not be available perhaps on submit a query can be made to see if exists then process accordingly?

I have reviewed and googled extensively for a complete example but haven't come across any. Tried several without luck. unfortunately my java script and jquery skills are non existent and trying to feel my way around code igniter.

I have review and attempted the below articles:
http://vortexdev.netii.net/article_17/Check_the_user_name_availability_with___Codeigniter_jQuery
[CodeIgniter - Checking to see if a value already exists in the database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4296930/codeigniter-checking-to-see-if-a-value-already-exists-in-the-database)
http://www.joshuawinn.com/check-if-email-username-exists-with-codeigniter-and-jquery-validation/

My code currently is:

**jquery link:**

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title><?php  echo $title; ?></title>
    <link href="<?php echo base_url();  ?>styles/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="<?php echo base_url();  ?>styles/menu.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>  
    <script type="text/javascript">

    </script>   
</head>
```

**My Controller:**

```
function create_customer()
    {

        $this->form_validation->set_rules("customer_name","`Customer Name`","required|min_length[6]|xss_clean");
        $this->form_validation->set_rules("address_line_1","`Address Line 1`","required|xss_clean|min_length[6]");
        $this->form_validation->set_rules("address_line_2","`Address Line 2`","xss_clean|min_length[6]");
        $this->form_validation->set_rules("suburb","`Suburb`","required|xss_clean|min_length[6]");
        $this->form_validation->set_rules("city","`City`","required|xss_clean|min_length[6]");
        $this->form_validation->set_rules("postalcode","`Postal Code`","required|xss_clean|min_length[4]|max_length[5]");
        $this->form_validation->set_rules("primary_contact_name","`Contact Person Name`","required|xss_clean|min_length[6]");
        $this->form_validation->set_rules("primary_contact_email","`Contact Person email`","required|valid_email|xss_clean");
        $this->form_validation->set_rules("primary_contact_tell","`Contact Person tell`","required|xss_clean|min_length[10]|max_length[14]");

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
            $data["message"]="";

            $data['title']="Master Data Home Page";
            $this->load->view("master_data/view_master_data_header",$data);
            $this->load->view("master_data/view_master_data_nav");
            $this->load->view("master_data/view_content_master_data_create_customer");
            $this->load->view("master_data/view_master_data_footer");
        } else {

        $data = array(
            'customer_name' =>  $this->input->post('customer_name'),
            'address_line_1' =>  $this->input->post('address_line_1'),
            'address_line_2' =>  $this->input->post('address_line_2'),
            'suburb' =>  $this->input->post('suburb'),
            'city' =>  $this->input->post('city'),
            'postalcode' =>  $this->input->post('postalcode'),
            'primary_contact_name' =>  $this->input->post('primary_contact_name'),
            'primary_contact_email' =>  $this->input->post('primary_contact_email'),
            'primary_contact_tell' =>  $this->input->post('primary_contact_tell'),
            );

        $this->model_master_data->add_record($data);

        $this->customer_created_successfully();
            }
        }
```

**and my view:**

```
<?php
echo validation_errors();
?>
<br>
<?php 
    echo form_open('masterdata/create_customer');
?>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td valign="top">

<?php   

    echo form_label("Customer Name", "customer_name");
    $data= array(
    "name"=>"customer_name",
    "id"=>"customer_name",
    "value"=>set_value("customer_name"));
    echo form_input($data);

    echo form_label("Contact Name", "primary_contact_name");
    $data= array(
    "name"=>"primary_contact_name",
    "id"=>"primary_contact_name",
    "value"=>set_value("primary_contact_name"));
    echo form_input($data);

        echo form_label("Contact Email", "primary_contact_email");
    $data= array(
    "name"=>"primary_contact_email",
    "id"=>"primary_contact_email",
    "value"=>set_value("primary_contact_email"));
    echo form_input($data);


    echo form_label("Contact Tel", "primary_contact_tell");
    $data= array(
    "name"=>"primary_contact_tell",
    "id"=>"primary_contact_tell",
    "value"=>set_value("primary_contact_tell"));
    echo form_input($data);

    ?>
    </td>
    <td width="20">
    <td valign="top">
    <?php

    echo form_label("Address Line 1", "address_line_1");
    $data= array(
    "name"=>"address_line_1",
    "id"=>"address_line_1",
    "value"=>set_value("address_line_1"));
    echo form_input($data);

    echo form_label("Address Line 2", "address_line_2");
    $data= array(
    "name"=>"address_line_2",
    "id"=>"address_line_2",
    "value"=>set_value("address_line_2"));
    echo form_input($data);

    echo form_label("Suburb", "suburb");
    $data= array(
    "name"=>"suburb",
    "id"=>"suburb",
    "value"=>set_value("suburb"));
    echo form_input($data);

    echo form_label("City", "city");
    $data= array(
    "name"=>"city",
    "id"=>"city",
    "value"=>set_value("city"));
    echo form_input($data);

    echo form_label("Postal Code", "postalcode");
    $data= array(
    "name"=>"postalcode",
    "id"=>"postalcode",
    "value"=>set_value("postalcode"));
    echo form_input($data);

    ?>
    </td>
        </tr>
            </table>
<br>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Add New Record">
    </p>
<br>
<?php 
    echo form_close();
?>
```

Any advice is really appreciated as always. if you know of a complete working example or tutorial I can follow please advise.

Thanks again,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok this will give you hint

```
     <script type="text/javascript" >
      function registerForm(id)
    {
      $('#user_error').html('');    


  var name        = $.trim($('#name').val());


   if(name=='')
  {
      $('#user_email_error').html('All fields are required!');
      return false;
  }


  $.ajax({
  type  :   'POST',
  data    :   $('#form-register').serialize(),
  url       :   '<?=base_url()?>login/register_user',
  cache : false,    
  success: function(data){
        if(data=='name')
        {
            $('#user_error').html('This name is already in use try new one!');
            return false;   
        }



        else 
        {                   
            document.location.href='<?=base_url()?>login';
        }
      }

      });

  return false;

    }
      </script>
```

this one in your contoller

```
     function register_user()
{
    $str = '';

    $user_email =   $this->input->post('email');
    $name=  $this->input->post('name');
    $data_a['name']         = $name;

        $result1     =      $this->login_model->check_username($name);

        if($result1->num_rows() > 0 )
        { 
            $str = 'name';   
        }


    else
    { 
        $this->login_model->add_user($data_a);

        $str = 'goo';


     }
     echo($str);


     exit;
}
```

this is view

```
     <div id="user_error" style="color:#FF0000; font-size:13px; font-weight:bold"></div>
    <form method="post" action="" id="form-register" title="Register" onSubmit="return registerForm(this)">


            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" class="input-unstyled" placeholder="Your name" autocomplete="off">



                    <button type="submit" id="send-register">Register</button>
           </form>
```

Comment: Thanks. are `check_email_user` and `check_username` built in functions or do you have the model syntax? I assume the first block of code is to go in the header of my view? Thanks again.

Comment: i have edit code jst ignore check_email_user
bt check_username is a function that i made in controller to check user. u will make it depends on your table