# create function to validate existing user / new user

Tags: php, codeigniter

How do i check if the user already exist in the database. I can create user but not very sure how to check if the user already exist in the databas. here are my code:
view file

```
<?php echo $this->navigasi->top(); ?>

<div class="container">
    <br>
    <h4 style="margin:0 auto;width:650px;">CREATE USER ACCOUNT</h4>
    <br>
    <form class="form-horizontal the-form" method="post" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>admin/register_account">
    <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('mesej'); ?>  
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label">Name Staff:</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" required name="nama_staf" class="input-xlarge">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label">Password:</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="password" required  name="kata_laluan" class="input-xlarge">
            </div>
        </div>

         <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label"> Email:</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="email" name="email" class="input-xlarge">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label">Position:</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <select name="jawatan" class="span3" id="jawatan">
                <option value="1">Clerk</option>
                <option value="2">Technician</option>
                <option value="3">Assitant officer</option>
                <option value="4">Officer</option>                  
                <option value="5">Director</option>                 
              </select>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label">No. Staff:</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" required name="no_staf" class="input-xlarge">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label"></label>
            <div class="controls">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="icon-user icon-white"></i> Register</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;
```

**controller file**

```
class Admin extends MY_Controller {

public function index()
{
    $session_data = $this->session->userdata('account');
    $data['sesi_jenis'] = $session_data['jenis'];

    if($data['sesi_jenis'] < 1)
    {
        redirect('utama');
    } else {
        $this->load->view('view-utama-pentadbir');
    }
}

public function register()
{
    $this->load->view('view-create-account');
}

public function register_account()
{
    $query = $this->modeluser->createAccount();

    $this->session->set_flashdata('mesej', '<span class="label label-info">Account created!</span> ');
    redirect(base_url().'admin/register');
```

**model file**

```
class ModelUser extends CI_Model {

public function creatAccount()
{
    $nameStaf   =   $_POST['nama_staf'];
    $noStaf     =   $_POST['no_staf'];
    $email      =   $_POST['email'];
    $password   =   sha1($_POST['password']);
    $jenis      =   0;  // user is 0 - admin is 1
    $position   =   $_POST['position'];

    $this->db->query("INSERT INTO akaun (nama_staf,no_staf,email,password,jenis,position) VALUES ('$namaStaf','$noStaf','$email','$password','$jenis','$position')");

}

public function padamAkaun($no_staf)
{
    $this->db->query("DELETE FROM akaun WHERE no_staf = '$no_staf'");
}
```

Comment: you can perform a query with the given username and email  before insert

Comment: Try checking with email id.If email id exists then say user alderady exists.

Comment: THATS MEAN I SHOULD CREATE CODE WITH FORM VALIDATION BEFORE INSERT IN MODEL??

Answer (score 0):

change model as per.considering email is unique for each user

```
class ModelUser extends CI_Model {

    public function creatAccount()
    {
        $nameStaf   =   $_POST['nama_staf'];
        $noStaf     =   $_POST['no_staf'];
        $email      =   $_POST['email'];
        $password   =   sha1($_POST['password']);
        $jenis      =   0;  // user is 0 - admin is 1
        $position   =   $_POST['position'];
        if ($this->checkEmailExist($email) == false)
            return 'ERROR! DUPLICATE USER';// or handle as you like
        $this->db->query("INSERT INTO akaun (nama_staf,no_staf,email,password,jenis,position)
        VALUES ('$namaStaf','$noStaf','$email','$password','$jenis','$position')");

    }


    public function padamAkaun($no_staf)
    {
        $this->db->query("DELETE FROM akaun WHERE no_staf = '$no_staf'");
    }


   private function checkEmailExist($email)
  {
     $this->db->where('email', $email);
     $query = $this->db->get('akaun');
     if( $query->num_rows() == 0 ){ return TRUE; } else { return FALSE; }
  }
```

Comment: thic code received error on line $user_count...fatal error:call to undefined function result...i prefer to use username instead of email id

Comment: i dont have code igniter right now. Please use result_array funnction. weather it helps. or just search out

Comment: hi susheel...thanks for your correction but u can u make it work for me??

Comment: try now, code improved. check this url also
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4296930/codeigniter-checking-to-see-if-a-value-already-exists-in-the-database

Comment: no error displayed when running the system, but wheni try to register same email address, the system automatically adjust the email like this; if the existing email is a@gmail.com and i try register the same email it drop one letter like this a@gmail.co and creates new account.

Comment: You have not handled public function register()
{
    $this->load->view('view-create-account');
}

this function in controller for 
"return 'ERROR! DUPLICATE USER';// or handle as you like" this case, handle all case[already existing id] , then you will get clear understanding

Comment: I have not improved the code ,just remove error, copy paste from op

Answer (score 0):

```
In your controller function set validation rule as:
$this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', trim|required|valid_email|is_unique[tabelname.columnname]|xss_clean');
```

Comment: i m still in blur...many attempt does not work...pls help me with correct codes...only this is my problem running the system..thank u very much

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email','trim|required|valid_email|is_unique[tabelname.columnname]|xss_clean');
$this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="error">', '</div>');
if($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE)
{
// action after validation success.
}else{
//action after validation failure.
}
```