# how to check if username already exists in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am working on a site in codeigniter.I am not so expert using framework.Here I have to check if email already exists in database.I have coded the required functionality but I am getting an error when submit the form.
In controller i have made the following rule.

My code is:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules(
    'email', 'Email', 'trim|required|valid_email|is_unique|callback_isEmailExist'
);
public function isEmailExist($email) {
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->load->model('user');
    $is_exist = $this->user->isEmailExist($email);

    if ($is_exist) {
        $this->form_validation->set_message(
            'isEmailExist', 'Email address is already exist.'
        );    
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

in model user the function is :

```
function isEmailExist($email) {
    $this->db->select('id');
    $this->db->where('email', $email);
    $query = $this->db->get('users');

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

When I submit the form, I am getting the following errors.

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined offset: 1

Filename: libraries/Form_validation.php

### Line Number: 953

A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE ` = 'muraddnw@gmail.com' LIMIT 1' at line 2

SELECT * WHERE ` = 'muraddnw@gmail.com' LIMIT 1

Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\aunction\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 330
Anyone help me please.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The db query from the error is not the query generated in the model you've shown us.

Comment: is there something wrong with my code ?? can you help in this ?

Comment: @user2702406 I have edited the isEmailExist() function of your model, Can you try if it works? I have added 'false' parameter in  $this->db->select('id',false);

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18094456/create-function-to-validate-existing-user-new-user/18094861#18094861

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is in the set_rules line. Here you use both `is_unique` and a `callback` function. You have to use anyone of that. If you use a call_back function to check duplicate data; doesn't need to use is_unique. `For this wrong you get that error` Just remove the `is_unique` from there.

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('email','Email','trim|required|valid_email|callback_isEmailExist'); // removed is_unique
```

Try this out and let me know.

Comment: In your model isEmailExist() function you use $this->db->select('id'); I think this is not needed here; Because this function is just return TRUE or FALSE.

Answer (score 2):

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'userName', 'required|callback_exists_username');


#uniqueness of username
    function exists_username($str)
    {
        $record_id = $this->input->post('record_id');
        $condition = array('user_id !='=>$record_id,'username'=>$str);
        $value =GetAllRecord('user_master',$condition,$is_single=true);
        if (count($value) == 0)
        {
            return TRUE;
        }
        else
        {
            $this->form_validation->set_message('exists_username', 'username already exists!');
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add `is_unique[tablename.fieldname]` rules to the form validation. for Example:

```
 array('field' => 'email', 'label' => 'Email', 'rules' => 'trim|required|valid_email|is_unique[users.email]'));
```

Comment: This works with CI 3. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your Model is like

```
$this->db->select('id');
$this->db->where('email', $email);
```

please tell the mysql from which table you want to get the record.

`$this->db->from('tablename');`

it would be like

```
$this->db->select('id');
$this->db->from('tablename');
$this->db->where('email', $email);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in the mysql query:-

```
SELECT * WHERE ` = 'muraddnw@gmail.com' LIMIT 1
```

Your code has not specified which table to query from. So use following:-

```
$this->db->select('id');
$this->db->from('tablename');
$this->db->where('email', $email);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

no need to a make a special function, this is enough

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules(
    'email', 'Email', 'trim|required|valid_email|is_unique'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `is_unique[table.field]` add table name and field.

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules(
    'email', 'Email', 'trim|required|valid_email|is_unique[table.field]|callback_isEmailExist'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can check if a field is unique or not by using form_validator function `is_unique[table_name.field_name]`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: the validation method in code ignitor for making the field is given as code in `is_unique[table_name.field_name]` syntax